# Positive voltage with an inverting buck boost

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost

in the inverting buck boost the output is Vout = -Vin(d/(1-d)) , where d is the duty cycle of the switch.
The output voltage is alsways negative. In my case the input voltage is provided by a battery.
Is it possible to attach a load that requires a positive voltage supply simply by inverting its terminals?
I'm asking this question because I can't understand why on the internet I found inverting and not-inverting buck boost converter.

Thanks

[image: buck boost circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your load is isolated you could hook it "backwards" across the output of an inverting buck-boost.

The reason you find non-inverting buck-boost converters is because often the load has to be referred to the same ground as other rails in the system, and you can't connect its ground to the negative rail and positive to the system ground.

For example, suppose you have a microprocessor that runs from a battery.  It also needs a 3.3V rail for some I/O.  You could use a buck-boost from the battery to generate the 3.3V, but it has to be referenced to the same ground as the battery and the uC.  Therefore you need a non-inverting buck-boost.

The non-inverting buck-boosts have the disadvantage of needing 4 switches, or in some topologies a capacitor that has to handle the full load current. (e.g. SEPIC)